# How to show navigation bar in my android app created with unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating android app with Unity. Although I deleted this statement

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

It's still not showing navigation bar in my app. Can you help me someone?

Folder Path is  *MyUnityProject/Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml*  and 
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.VideoPlayer"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">

        </activity>
        <!--
            To support devices using the TI S3D library for stereo mode we must
            add the following library.
            Devices that require this are: ODG X6
        -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.ti.s3d" android:required="false" />
        <!--
            To support the ODG R7 in stereo mode we must add the following library.
        -->
        <uses-library android:name="com.osterhoutgroup.api.ext" android:required="false" />
    </application>
</manifest>

<!-- android:installLocation="preferExternal" -->
```

Comment: What is the folder path of the AndroidManifest.xml file you modified? Also, post your whole xml code.

Comment: @Programmer Folder Path is MyUnityProject/Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml  and whole code is following.

Comment: Post that in your question. Edit and post it.

Comment: @Programmer . OK , Sir.

Answer (score 2):

This is achieved by turning off full screen mode.

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    Screen.fullScreen = false;
#endif
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-fullScreen.html